# Eclipse step debug into interface method directly

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

I have an interface

```
public interface Trumpistan {
  public boolean impeachable(Charge[] charges, Evidence evidence);
  public int getTweetsPerDay();
  public boolean watchTV();
  public void mkHyperbolicStatement(Topic topic);
}
```

I am now step debugging the line with "proceed = trumpistania.impeachable" in Eclipse

```
Trumpistan trumpistania = MarALago.factory();
boolean proceed = trumpistania.impeachable(
   getAttorneyGenFactory().getAttorneyGen().getSpecialCounsel().getSecretReport().getCharges(),
   getEvidenceFactory().collate(getEvidenceFactory().getSources())
);
```

I want to step into trumpistania.impeachable(...) directly but I can't because

- it is an interface method and [go to definition] on trumpistania.impeachable would lead to the interface method definition.
- Pressing F5 or step-into would lead me into a nearly endless grid of function calls and reflection checking.

What is the best strategy to step directly into the implemented code of trumpistania.impeachable ?

ADDITIONAL question.

- What is the best strategy to step directly into the implemented method of getCharges() when step debugging

  - getAttorneyGenFactory().getAttorneyGen().getSpecialCounsel().getSecretReport().getCharges()

I don't have access to modify the code. It is a maven artefact.

Comment: A simple approach is find all implementing classes and set breakpoint inside their `impeachable` methods.

Comment: ... by pressing `ctrl + t` (Quick Type Heirarchy) with cursor on the method name.